# How can I insert a correct format in datetime data type?

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have a syntax here that is working if the data type of column `Date` is varchar and because since it needs to be in datetime data type it wont work and it always say `"Incorrect datetime value: 'October 8, 2015' for column 'Date' at row 1"`. Is there something wrong in my format?

Edit: I want the date format to show like May 1,2012.

Im using procedure.

here is what i got:

```
INSERT INTO TEMPORARY(ISBN,title,author,First_Name,Last_Name,STATUS,DATE,Return_Date,UserID)

VALUES (i,t,a,f,l,1,DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%M %e, %Y'),DATE_FORMAT(NOW()+ INTERVAL 3 DAY, '%M %e, %Y'),u);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `DATE_FORMAT` when inserting a date into a `DATETIME` column.

```
INSERT INTO TEMPORARY(ISBN,title,author,First_Name,Last_Name,STATUS,DATE,Return_Date,UserID)
VALUES (i,t,a,f,l,1,NOW(),NOW()+ INTERVAL 3 DAY,u);
```

If you want the date to appear in a specific format when you query, use `DATE_FORMAT(Return_Date, '%M %e, %Y')` in the `SELECT` query.

Comment: ow so `DATE_FORMAT` is only used in select query
thank you and it works and I learned something from you.
@RahulTripathi thanks to you too

Comment: It can be used in an INSERT query if you want to insert a string.